# Checking all checkboxes of table body with checkbox in table head angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, html-table, checked

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width: 100%; padding-top:10px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary textalign">
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>SonVin Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Venue Name</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkall" /><span style="margin-left:10px;">Add Invoice</span></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="data in getdataintable">
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="cursor:pointer">Details</a></td>
                            <td>{{data.sonvinid}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.venuename}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.location}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.area}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.amount}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is my table,
here I have this line( `<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" /><span style="margin-left:10px;">Add All Invoice</span></th>`).

This indicates that if a user checked this checkbox, all the other checkboxes should also be checked.
Now what I want is if a particular user clicks on a checkbox on thead, all the checkboxes of td also be check and all the data of `<td>{{data.sonvinid}}</td>`
should be stored in the array in my controller of angularjs.

```
$scope.storeall=[];
```

I want to do this with angularjs,
anyone here who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

make inside your controller some methods like this

method to select All

method for deselect All

method for toggle between above

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]) // the app module 
app.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.storeall = [];
    $scope.selectAllFlag = false;
    $scope.getdataintable = [
       {sonvinid:1, date : "string" , venuename: "String Name"  },
       {sonvinid:2, date : "string" , venuename: "String Name" }
    ];
    $scope.checkAllToggle = funciton(){
       if(!$scope.selectAllFlag){
         $scope.selectAll();
         $scope.selectAllFlag = true;
       }else {
         $scope.deselectAll();
          $scope.selectAllFlag = false;
       }
    };
    $scope.selectAll = function(){
       for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.data.length ; i++){
            $scope.getdataintable[i].selected = true;
            $scope.storeall.push($scope.data[i].sonvinid);
       }
    };

    $scope.deselectAll = function(){
        for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.data.length ; i++){
            $scope.getdataintable[i].selected = false;
            $scope.storeall = [];
       }
    };
});
```

to Use it on HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" ng-controller="tableCtrl" style="width: 100%; padding-top:10px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary textalign">
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>SonVin Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Venue Name</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAllToggle()" /><span style="margin-left:10px;">Add Invoice</span></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="data in getdataintable">
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="cursor:pointer">Details</a></td>
                            <td>{{data.sonvinid}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.venuename}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.location}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.area}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.amount}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.selected" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```